# wsdl in API automation testing

Tags: wsdl, automated-tests, rest-assured, karate

Is it possible to use WSDL in rest assured, I'm looking for open source API automation testing tool. My services are in WSDL, I can use SOAPUI which will extract wsdl into separate end points. but Is there any way can we extract end in WSDL manually or else how I can use this with Karate or Rest Assured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate), let me give you my point of view.

You don't need to worry about WSDL. All you need is a sample SOAP envelope as XML (plain-text) and you will be easily able to derive all your tests, complex scenarios and edge cases with that. This is what many teams are doing today, and you can refer this detailed set of examples to get a sense of the possibilities: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)

Even if you have some complexities like encryption and signed-headers etc, you can easily plug them into your tests using Java-interop, look at this example in the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-basic-authentication-example

Comment: If you don't mind, can I get any brief tutorial blog or website to start Karate for SOAP API testing

Comment: @user2986491 please search for "soap" on this page: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo